# AppleScript: How to return to previous dialog/list?

Tags: applescript

A fairly basic problem here, but I have no AppleScript experience.

Made a list with multiple selections and if/then conditions. Made a selection to display a dialog with one button that takes you back to the list. I know theres no "go to line" in AppleScript, so what would be the best way to do this?

The essence of what I want:

```
set A to "smb://XXX"
set B to "smb://XXX"
set servers to {"A", "B"}

set chosen to (choose from list servers with title "Servers" with prompt "Connect to:" OK button name "Connect" cancel button name "Abort" with multiple selections allowed) as text

try
if (text of chosen) is "A" then
    mount volume (A as string)
end if

if (text of chosen) is "B" then
        beep
        display dialog "Not available yet" as text with icon stop with title "Error" buttons {"Back"} default button 1
```

How do I go back to the list here?
I cant rewrite the "choose from list". Is there a

```
if result = {button returned:"Back"} then
```

way of doing it?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is recursion. Create a method for your code, within the method if the answer is "Back", call the method again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after.  I tried not to modify your original code much, but I think there are some things you could improve in it. For example you're allowing multiple selections, but you don't have a way of handling if they select both A & B.

```
on run
    chooseServer()
end run

on chooseServer()
    set A to "smb://XXX"
    set B to "smb://XXX"
    set servers to {"A", "B"}

    set chosen to (choose from list servers with title "Servers" with prompt "Connect to:" OK button name "Connect" cancel button name "Abort" with multiple selections allowed) as text

    if (text of chosen) is "A" then
        try
            mount volume (A as string)
        on error e
            display dialog e giving up after 5
        end try
    else if (text of chosen) is "B" then
        beep
        if button returned of (display dialog "Not available yet" as text with icon stop with title "Error" buttons {"Back"} default button 1) = "Back" then
            chooseServer() -- recursive call
        end if
    end if
end chooseServer
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

The `on chooseServer()` did the trick. I can't see the need for the run though? Works without it?

As for the multiple selection; i've never encountered any problems doing it my way. I have 12 different mounts. Guess it just runs the if's in order? How else would I address multiple selections?

The `on error`you described is not preferred. I already get a notification if fails.