# How do you create a list based on a previous list's variable

Tags: list, applescript

I have a list of choices. Whatever choice you make in the list should determine the choices available in the next list. I'm currently receiving

**error** "Can’t get item 1 of \"\"." number -1728 from item 1 **of** ""

It seems that the set variable from the first list is not feeding into the If Else If statement.

```
    set currentSupport to "" -- initialize the variable
    set supportList to choose from list {"A", "B"} with prompt "Source:" default items {"A"}
    set currentSupport to result

    set currentPR to "" -- initialize the variable
    if currentSupport is "A" then
        set misrouteList to choose from list {"1", "2", "3", "4"} with title "Prepared Responses" with prompt "Reason:"
        set currentPR to result
    else if currentSupport is "B" then
        set misrouteList to choose from list {"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"} with title "Prepared Responses" with prompt "Reason:"
        set currentPR to result
    end if


    set supportChoice to item 1 of currentSupport
    set prChoice to item 1 of currentPR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`choose from list` returns `false` if the user presses `Cancel` or a **list** of items even `with multiple selections` is not enabled.

You have to flatten the list **before** the `if - else` expression

```
set currentSupport to "" -- initialize the variable
set supportList to choose from list {"A", "B"} with prompt "Source:" default items {"A"}
if supportList is false then return
set currentSupport to item 1 of supportList

set currentPR to "" -- initialize the variable
if currentSupport is "A" then
    set misrouteList to choose from list {"1", "2", "3", "4"} with title "Prepared Responses" with prompt "Reason:"
    if misrouteList is false then return
    set currentPR to item 1 of misrouteList
else if currentSupport is "B" then
    set misrouteList to choose from list {"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"} with title "Prepared Responses" with prompt "Reason:"
    if misrouteList is false then return
    set currentPR to item 1 of misrouteList
end if


set supportChoice to currentSupport
set prChoice to currentPR
```

or without redundant code

```
set supportList to choose from list {"A", "B"} with prompt "Source:" default items {"A"}
if supportList is false then return
set currentSupport to item 1 of supportList

if currentSupport is "A" then
    set responseList to {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
else -- there is only A or B
    set responseList to {"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}
end if
set misrouteList to choose from list responseList with title "Prepared Responses" with prompt "Reason:"
if misrouteList is false then return
set currentPR to item 1 of misrouteList

set supportChoice to currentSupport
set prChoice to currentPR
```

or keep the selection as list and check for `{"A"}`

```
set supportList to choose from list {"A", "B"} with prompt "Source:" default items {"A"}
if supportList is false then return
if supportList is {"A"} then
    set responseList to {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
else
    set responseList to {"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}
end if
set misrouteList to choose from list responseList with title "Prepared Responses" with prompt "Reason:"
if misrouteList is false then return

set supportChoice to item 1 of supportList
set prChoice to item 1 of misrouteList
```

Comment: I wasn't able to use the more elegant, less redundant code since the initial list actually has 12 items in it instead of just the two in my example code and every additional list has at least three items. But the assistance you provided worked wonderfully. Now I'm trying to figure out how to return to a previous list if you chose the wrong option. I found this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196822/applescript-how-to-return-to-previous-dialog-list) which covers most of it, but there's one dumb list option that goes two layers deep and I can't figure out how to nest them.