# Return to a Previous Dialog Within a Dialog List Tree

Tags: applescript

I've been looking over [AppleScript: How to return to previous dialog/list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196822/applescript-how-to-return-to-previous-dialog-list) and it gave me a good jumping off point, however the solution only goes one dialog list deep. How would I go about having multiple Lists in a tree, where a Back button only sends you back one level, instead of all the way to the top level.

I've been reading over AppleScript Handlers, but I can't figure out how to have more than one.

Additionally, I am receiving an error in my code. If I cancel out of the first List, the dialog box closes as expected. But if I navigate into a one of the next dialog Lists then press Back and then press Cancel I receive **error** "Can’t get item 1 of false." number -1728 from *item* 1 of *false*

```
on run
    chooseLetter()
end run

on chooseLetter()

    set preparedResponse to "" -- initialize the variable
    set prList to choose from list {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"} with title "Greek Alphabet" with prompt "Alphabet Characters:" default items {""}
    if prList is false then return
    set preparedResponse to item 1 of prList

    set currentPR to "" -- initialize the variable
    if preparedResponse is "Alpha" then
        set articleList to choose from list {"Alpha One", "Alpha Two", "Alpha Three", "Alpha Four"} with title "Alpha Title" with prompt "Alpha Choices:" OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"
        if articleList is false then chooseLetter()
        set currentPR to item 1 of articleList

    else if preparedResponse is "Beta" then
        set articleList to choose from list {"Beta One", "Beta Two", "Beta Three", "Beta Four", "Beta Five"} with title "Beta Title" with prompt "Beta Choices:" default items {"Beta One"} OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"

        if articleList is false then chooseLetter()
        set currentPR to item 1 of articleList

    else if preparedResponse is "Gamma" then
        set articleList to choose from list {"Epsilon", "Zeta"} with title "Gamma Title" with prompt "Gamma Choices:" default items {"Epsilon"} OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"

        if articleList is false then chooseLetter()
        set currentPR to item 1 of articleList

    else if preparedResponse is "Delta" then
        set articleList to choose from list {"Delta One", "Delta Two", "Delta Three"} with title "Delta Title" with prompt "Delta Choices:" default items {"Delta Three"} OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"

        if articleList is false then chooseLetter()
        set currentPR to item 1 of articleList

    end if

    set letterGroup to preparedResponse
    set prChoice to currentPR
    set prResponseCode to "" -- initialize the variable


    #Alpha

    if letterGroup is "Alpha" and prChoice is "Alpha One" then
        set prResponseCode to "α 1000"


    else if letterGroup is "Alpha" and prChoice is "Alpha Two" then
        set prResponseCode to "α 1001"


    else if letterGroup is "Alpha" and prChoice is "Alpha Three" then
        set categoryList to choose from list {"Eta", "Theta"} with title "Alpha Three Title" with prompt "Alpha Three Choices:" OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"

        if categoryList is false then chooseLetter()
        set categoryError to item 1 of categoryList

        if categoryError is "Eta" then
            set the clipboard to "Eta is the seventh letter of the Greek alphabet. Originally denoting a consonant /h/, its sound value in the classical Attic dialect of Ancient Greek was a long vowel, raised to [i] in hellenistic Greek, a process known as iotacism."
        else if categoryError is "Theta" then
            set the clipboard to "Theta is the eighth letter of the Greek alphabet, derived from the Phoenician letter Teth. In the system of Greek numerals it has the value 9."
        end if
        set prResponseCode to "α 1002"


    else if letterGroup is "Alpha" and prChoice is "Alpha Four" then
        set prResponseCode to "α 1003"



        # Beta

    else if letterGroup is "Beta" and prChoice is "Beta One" then
        set prResponseCode to "β 2000"


    else if letterGroup is "Beta" and prChoice is "Beta Two" then
        set prResponseCode to "β 2001"


    else if letterGroup is "Beta" and prChoice is "Beta Three" then
        set prResponseCode to "β 2002"


    else if letterGroup is "Beta" and prChoice is "Beta Four" then
        set prResponseCode to "β 2003"


    else if letterGroup is "Beta" and prChoice is "Beta Five" then
        set prResponseCode to "β 2004"




        # Gamma

    else if letterGroup is "Gamma" then

        set misrouteGroup to "" -- initialize the variable
        if prChoice is "Epsilon" then
            set misrouteList to choose from list {"Epsilon One", "Epsilon Two", "Epsilon Three", "Epsilon Four"} with title "Epsilon Title" with prompt "Epsilon Choices:" OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"

            if misrouteList is false then chooseLetter()
            set misrouteGroup to item 1 of misrouteList
        else if prChoice is "Zeta" then
            set misrouteList to choose from list {"Zeta One", "Zeta Two", "Zeta Three", "Zeta Four", "Zeta Five", "Zeta Six"} with title "Zeta Title" with prompt "Zeta Choices:" OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"

            if misrouteList is false then chooseLetter()
            set misrouteGroup to item 1 of misrouteList
        end if
        if prChoice is "Epsilon" and misrouteGroup is "Epsilon One" then
            set prResponseCode to "ε 5000"


        else if prChoice is "Epsilon" and misrouteGroup is "Epsilon Two" then
            set prResponseCode to "ε 5001"


        else if prChoice is "Epsilon" and misrouteGroup is "Epsilon Three" then
            set prResponseCode to "ε 5002"


        else if prChoice is "Epsilon" and misrouteGroup is "Epsilon Four" then
            set prResponseCode to "ε 5003"


        else if prChoice is "Zeta" and misrouteGroup is "Zeta One" then
            set prResponseCode to "ζ 6000"


        else if prChoice is "Zeta" and misrouteGroup is "Zeta Two" then
            set prResponseCode to "ζ 6001"


        else if prChoice is "Zeta" and misrouteGroup is "Zeta Three" then
            set prResponseCode to "ζ 6002"


        else if prChoice is "Zeta" and misrouteGroup is "Zeta Four" then
            set prResponseCode to "ζ 6003"


        else if prChoice is "Zeta" and misrouteGroup is "Zeta Five" then
            set prResponseCode to "ζ 6004"


        else if prChoice is "Zeta" and misrouteGroup is "Zeta Six" then
            set prResponseCode to "ζ 6005"

        end if



        # Delta

    else if letterGroup is "Delta" and prChoice is "Delta One" then
        set prResponseCode to "δ 4000"


    else if letterGroup is "Delta" and prChoice is "Delta Two" then
        set prResponseCode to "δ 4001"


    else if letterGroup is "Delta" and prChoice is "Delta Three" then
        set prResponseCode to "δ 4002"

    end if


    set prResponseCode to "Classic " & prResponseCode

    set textToType to prResponseCode

end chooseLetter
```

From the Dialog List "Alpha Three Choices:" I want to be able to return to the List "Alpha Choices:" and "Epsilon Choices" should go back to "Gamma Choices:" Right now everything goes back to the top level "Alphabet Characters:"

Answer (score 1):

The error `Can’t get item 1 of false." number -1728 from item 1 of false` is pretty clear.

First of all the rule is: A `return` statement exits the current scope. In the `on run` handler it aborts the script because it's on the top level.

So far so good.

However you recursively call `chooseLetter()` so pressing the `Cancel` button (or whatever its name is) continues after the line `chooseLetter()` was called.

I recommend to work with handlers. A handler represents a single scope.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to make it work. I'm not excited about having to use `error number -128` but other than that, the whole thing is working great.

There's probably more elegant ways to write this, but it's a good start for me.

```
on run
    global preparedResponse, prResponseCode, articleList
    set prResponseFinal to "" -- intialize the variable
    set textToType to "" -- intialize the variable
    chooseLetter()
    activate application "TextEdit"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
        keystroke textToType
    end tell
end run

on chooseLetter()
    set prList to "" -- intialize the variable
    set prList to choose from list {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"} with title "Greek Alphabet" with prompt "Alphabet Characters:" default items {""}
    if prList is false then
        error number -128
    else
        set preparedResponse to item 1 of prList
    end if
    set letterGroup to preparedResponse
    set prResponseCode to "" -- initialize the variable
    if preparedResponse is "Alpha" then chooseAlpha()
    if preparedResponse is "Beta" then chooseBeta()
    if preparedResponse is "Gamma" then chooseGamma()
    if preparedResponse is "Delta" then chooseDelta()
end chooseLetter


# Alpha

on chooseAlpha()
    global preparedResponse, prResponseCode, articleList, textToType
    set preparedResponse to "" -- intialize the variable
    set prResponseCode to "" -- intialize the variable
    set articleList to "" -- initialize the variable
    set articleList to choose from list {"Alpha One", "Alpha Two", "Alpha Three", "Alpha Four"} with title "Alpha Title" with prompt "Alpha Choices:" OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"
    if articleList is false then
        chooseLetter()
    else
        set preparedResponse to item 1 of articleList
    end if
    if preparedResponse is "Alpha One" then set prResponseCode to "α 1000"
    if preparedResponse is "Alpha Two" then set prResponseCode to "α 1001"
    if preparedResponse is "Alpha Three" then chooseAlpha2()
    if preparedResponse is "Alpha Four" then set prResponseCode to "α 1003"
    set prResponseFinal to "Classic " & prResponseCode
    set textToType to prResponseFinal
end chooseAlpha


# Alpha2

on chooseAlpha2()
    global preparedResponse, prResponseCode, articleList
    set preparedResponse to "" -- intialize the variable
    set prResponseCode to "" -- initialize the variable
    set categoryList to "" -- initialize the variable
    set categoryList to choose from list {"Eta", "Theta"} with title "Alpha Three Title" with prompt "Alpha Three Choices:" OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"
    if categoryList is false then
        chooseAlpha()
    else
        set preparedResponse to item 1 of categoryList
    end if
    if preparedResponse is "Eta" then
        set the clipboard to "Eta is the seventh letter of the Greek alphabet. Originally denoting a consonant /h/, its sound value in the classical Attic dialect of Ancient Greek was a long vowel, raised to [i] in hellenistic Greek, a process known as iotacism."
        set prResponseCode to "η 7000"
    end if
    if preparedResponse is "Theta" then
        set the clipboard to "Theta is the eighth letter of the Greek alphabet, derived from the Phoenician letter Teth. In the system of Greek numerals it has the value 9."
        set prResponseCode to "θ 8000"
    end if
end chooseAlpha2


# Beta

on chooseBeta()
    global preparedResponse, prResponseCode, articleList, textToType
    set preparedResponse to "" -- intialize the variable
    set prResponseCode to "" -- intialize the variable
    set articleList to "" -- initialize the variable
    set articleList to choose from list {"Beta One", "Beta Two", "Beta Three", "Beta Four", "Beta Five"} with title "Beta Title" with prompt "Beta Choices:" default items {"Beta One"} OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"
    if articleList is false then
        chooseLetter()
    else
        set preparedResponse to item 1 of articleList
    end if
    if preparedResponse is "Beta One" then set prResponseCode to "β 2000"
    if preparedResponse is "Beta Two" then set prResponseCode to "β 2001"
    if preparedResponse is "Beta Three" then set prResponseCode to "β 2002"
    if preparedResponse is "Beta Four" then set prResponseCode to "β 2003"
    if preparedResponse is "Beta Five" then set prResponseCode to "β 2004"
    set prResponseFinal to "Classic " & prResponseCode
    set textToType to prResponseFinal
end chooseBeta



# Gamma

on chooseGamma()
    global preparedResponse, prResponseCode, articleList
    set preparedResponse to "" -- intialize the variable
    set prResponseCode to "" -- intialize the variable
    set articleList to "" -- initialize the variable
    set articleList to choose from list {"Epsilon", "Zeta"} with title "Gamma Title" with prompt "Gamma Choices:" default items {"Epsilon"} OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"
    if articleList is false then
        chooseLetter()
    else
        set preparedResponse to item 1 of articleList
    end if
    if preparedResponse is "Epsilon" then chooseGamma2()
    if preparedResponse is "Zeta" then chooseGamma3()
end chooseGamma


# Gamma2

on chooseGamma2()
    global preparedResponse, prResponseCode, articleList, textToType
    set preparedResponse to "" -- intialize the variable
    set prResponseCode to "" -- intialize the variable
    set articleList to "" -- initialize the variable
    set misrouteList to choose from list {"Epsilon One", "Epsilon Two", "Epsilon Three", "Epsilon Four"} with title "Epsilon Title" with prompt "Epsilon Choices:" OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"
    if misrouteList is false then
        chooseGamma()
    else
        set preparedResponse to item 1 of misrouteList
    end if
    if preparedResponse is "Epsilon One" then set prResponseCode to "ε 5000"
    if preparedResponse is "Epsilon Two" then set prResponseCode to "ε 5001"
    if preparedResponse is "Epsilon Three" then set prResponseCode to "ε 5002"
    if preparedResponse is "Epsilon Four" then set prResponseCode to "ε 5003"
    set prResponseFinal to "Classic " & prResponseCode
    set textToType to prResponseFinal
end chooseGamma2


# Gamma3

on chooseGamma3()
    global preparedResponse, prResponseCode, articleList, textToType
    set preparedResponse to "" -- intialize the variable
    set prResponseCode to "" -- intialize the variable
    set articleList to "" -- initialize the variable
    set misrouteList to choose from list {"Zeta One", "Zeta Two", "Zeta Three", "Zeta Four", "Zeta Five", "Zeta Six"} with title "Zeta Title" with prompt "Zeta Choices:" OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"
    if misrouteList is false then
        chooseGamma()
    else
        set preparedResponse to item 1 of misrouteList
    end if
    if preparedResponse is "Zeta One" then set prResponseCode to "ζ 6000"
    if preparedResponse is "Zeta Two" then set prResponseCode to "ζ 6001"
    if preparedResponse is "Zeta Three" then set prResponseCode to "ζ 6002"
    if preparedResponse is "Zeta Four" then set prResponseCode to "ζ 6003"
    if preparedResponse is "Zeta Five" then set prResponseCode to "ζ 6004"
    if preparedResponse is "Zeta Six" then set prResponseCode to "ζ 6005"
    set prResponseFinal to "Classic " & prResponseCode
    set textToType to prResponseFinal
end chooseGamma3


# Delta

on chooseDelta()
    global preparedResponse, prResponseCode, articleList, textToType
    set preparedResponse to "" -- intialize the variable
    set prResponseCode to "" -- intialize the variable
    set articleList to "" -- initialize the variable
    set articleList to choose from list {"Delta One", "Delta Two", "Delta Three"} with title "Delta Title" with prompt "Delta Choices:" default items {"Delta Three"} OK button name "Next" cancel button name "Back"
    if articleList is false then
        chooseLetter()
    else
        set preparedResponse to item 1 of articleList
    end if
    if preparedResponse is "Delta One" then set prResponseCode to "δ 4000"
    if preparedResponse is "Delta Two" then set prResponseCode to "δ 4001"
    if preparedResponse is "Delta Three" then set prResponseCode to "δ 4002"
    set prResponseFinal to "Classic " & prResponseCode
    set textToType to prResponseFinal
end chooseDelta
```